# onchange event in select tag!

Tags: javascript, onchange

The following code should give me a 1 in ParentSelect if I change the option in the menu, but I am getting a 0. Can anyone tell me what is the error?

```
<input type="hidden" name="ParentSelect" value="0" />
<select class="style" onchange="document.forms[0].elements['ParentSelect']=1" >
<option value="NULL">NULL</option>
...
</select>
```

Here, I have two tables in the database. They contain some fields like ServerName, etc..

Suggestions?

Comment: Now can you see my code?

Answer (score 4):

You are directly assigning the value `1` to the property `document.forms[0].elements['ParentSelect']`, whereas you presumably mean to change the value of the element, which would be achieved like this:

`document.forms[0].elements['ParentSelect'].value = 1`

I agree with some of the other comments concerning the lack of valid HTML strucutre, and I would add that if you are going to reference the field via `document.forms[0]`, you may as well give the field an id property so you can simply use 'document.getElementById` so your code works regardless of the other forms on the page.  Anyway, using your method, here is the complete code:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="ParentSelect" value="0" />
    <select class="style" onchange="document.forms[0].elements['ParentSelect'].value=1" >
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Using an id instead:

```
<form>
    <input id="parentSelect" type="hidden" name="ParentSelect" value="0" />
    <select class="style" onchange="var e = document.getElementById('parentSelect'); if (e) e.value=1;" >
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: In response to a now-deleted comment: I would have to test this to verify that this is true in ALL browsers, but I am pretty sure you'd get the first element that uses the given ID (you do in any browser I am intimately familiar with).  To make this code more flexible, I would not use this approach at all for that very reason.  You'd be better off doing something like `this.form.elements['ParentSelect'].value = 1` - if you're going to stick with inline script.

Answer (score 3):

`document.forms[0].elements['ParentSelect']` returns whole input, if you want to set it's value use

```
document.forms[0].elements['ParentSelect'].value = 1
```